# unable to decode Icelandic dual byte character in response string of .net appliaction

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, app-config, httpresponse

I have an application build on c#. here is the snippet of my code

```
private void ProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
       HttpListenerContext context = httpListener.EndGetContext(result);
       HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
       HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
       NameValueCollection queryString = getQueryStringFromRequest(request);
       …….
}
```

The response I get is in English only. However, sometimes I get part of the response in other language, Like Icelandic. Then my application is not able to format the string accordingly. For example in queryString I get something like this:

```
{ ENTITY_NAME=Contact&OBJECT_NAME=Mr.+Hl%ufffd%ufffdar+Hl%ufffd%ufffdberg}
```

However object name should be **Mr. Hlíðar Hlíðberg**.

I understand that issue is with not able to parse it according to dual byte character. I tried something similar to:

```
if (queryString["OBJECT_NAME"] != null){
   string s_unicode = queryString["OBJECT_NAME"];
   System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_1 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
   System.Text.Encoding utf_8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
   byte[] utfBytes = utf_8.GetBytes(s_unicode);
   byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf_8, iso_8859_1, utfBytes);                  
   string msg = iso_8859_1.GetString(isoBytes);
 }
```

but still i am getting response like **Mr. Hl??ar Hl??berg**
but it didn’t worked for me. Also i never liked this method as its to specific and things needs to be hard coded for eg. the key in this case.

So, How do I do it. Can I do something through config file or generic?

Comment: I don't think the query string passed to you is correct. all of them are `%ufffd`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: what needs to be corrected then...something on the web page side or in my config file to get the correct string. Or is it related to Browser settings?